# Resolve imports from a barrel module with Rollup

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I have a simple library written in typescript which I bundle with Rollup. Now it got it's first dependeny: [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator). Although it's a typescript library I need to use the [commonjs plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-commonjs) for rollup. In general that works. However, if importing from the barrel `index.js` like

```
import { IsInt } from 'class-validator';
```

it fails with

```
[!] Error: 'IsInt' is not exported by node_modules/class-validator/index.js
```

Can I configure Rollup so that it recognizes the barrel imports? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the [namedExports](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs#custom-named-exports) option of the commonjs plugin:

```
commonjs({
    namedExports: {
      'class-validator': [ 'IsInt' ]
    }
})
```

That requires to add all used exports which is really not optimal. I don't want to change the build config because of a change in the code. But well, it works...